# Javascript - read Data from Server via PHP - remove HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova

I am coding an app with cordova and AngularJS. I have a database, insert, fetch etc my data via PHP.
Insert, update works fine but a simple get/fetch will return a lot of html tags. And I dont know why. I just want the results as a json object/array. Not more..

This is my php code:

```
$name=utf8_encode($_POST['name']);
$data=array();

$q=mysqli_query($con,"select name from Vorname where name='Marie'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){    
   $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And this is my js/angularjs function:

```
$scope.getVorname = function (name) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/myjeannie/www/php/json.php', {
         params: {name: name}
    }).success(function (response) {
         $scope.data = response;
         console.log($scope.data);
    });
};
```

I just want to get the name Marie. Not the HTML tags before. Just the last row with the array stuff. But my output is this:

```
<br />
<font size='1'>
<table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
   <tr>
      <th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\MyJeannie\www\php\json.php on line <i>5</i></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
   <tr>
      <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td>
      <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0012</td>
      <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>244592</td>
      <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td>
      <td title='C:\wamp\www\MyJeannie\www\php\json.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\json.php<b>:</b>0</td>
   </tr>
</table></font>
[{"name":"Marie"},{"name":"Marie"},{"name":"Marie"},{"name":"Marie"},{"name":"Marie"},{"name":"Marie"}]
```

I hope you could help me :)

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\MyJeannie\www\php\json.php on line 5` - The AJAX request is using `GET` but the PHP uses `POST` - change `$name=utf8_encode($_POST['name']);` to `$name=utf8_encode($_GET['name']);`

Comment: It's PHP error, you can turn off errors or fix this one.

Comment: @RamRaider shit, my mistake :D thank you.... thank you very much